# Machine Learning text comparison model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, text, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I am creating a machine learning model that essentially returns the correctness of one text to another.
For example; “the cat and a dog”, “a dog and the cat”. The model needs to be able to identify that some words (“cat”/“dog”) are more important/significant than others (“a”/“the”). I am not interested in conjunction words etc. **I would like to be able to tell the model which words are the most “significant”** and have it determine how correct text 1 is to text 2, with the “significant” words bearing more weight than others.

It also needs to be able to recognise that phrases don’t necessarily have to be in the same order. The two above sentences should be an extremely high match.

What is the basic algorithm I should use to go about this? Is there an alternative to just creating a dataset with thousands of example texts and a score of correctness?

I am only after a broad overview/flowchart/process/algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I think [**TF-IDF**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) might be a good fit to your problem, because:

1. Emphasis on words occurring in many documents (say, 90% of your sentences/documents contain the conjuction word 'and') is much smaller, essentially giving more weight to the more document specific phrasing (this is the IDF part).
2. Ordering in Term Frequency (TF) does not matter, as opposed to methods using sliding windows etc.
3. It is very lightweight when compared to representation oriented methods like the one mentioned above.

**Big drawback**: Your data, depending on the size of corpus, may have too many dimensions (the same number of dimensions as unique words), you could use stemming/lemmatization in order to mitigate this problem to some degree.

You may calculate similiarity between two TF-IDF vector using cosine similiarity for example.

**EDIT:** Woops, this question is 8 months old, sorry for the bump, maybe it will be of use to someone else though.

Comment: No problem! I eventually realised that text comparison was insufficient for my task. Thanks for the comprehensive answer tho